# TFS 2010 SP1 to 2015 U1 upgrade issue

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I work in a company where TFS 2010 SP1 is used and we are going to upgrade it to some of later versions. I've upgraded SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2012 and tried to upgrade to 2012, 2013 and 2015 version of TFS. And all the times I get the same error while upgrading our project collection. This issue is fatal and upgrade cannot proceed to the end. It doesn't matter if I install new version of TFS on the same or on the new hardware. This sample is from upgrade to TFS2015 U1 log.

```
[12:15:36.780] Executing step: Grant WorkItemTracking Project Provision Permissions
[12:15:36.780]   Executing step: 'Grant WorkItemTracking Project Provision Permissions' WorkItemTracking.GrantProvisionPermissions (1413 of 1808)
[12:15:36.823]   [Error] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[12:15:36.857]   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[12:15:36.857]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.WorkItemStepPerformer.GrantProvisionPermissions(IVssRequestContext targetRequestContext, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[12:15:36.857]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)
[12:15:36.857] Step failed: Grant WorkItemTracking Project Provision Permissions. Execution time: 77 milliseconds.
```

I've serched for solution in internet and it seems like all conditions are met. TFS 2010 SP1 is installed, I have admin permissions on machine and so on. Please help with this issue if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a project that has been deleted from TFS without deletion of source control folder. I deleted this project by TFSDeleteProject.exe and after that migration goes right way.

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check the account you use to upgrade TFS.  To perform this procedure, you must be a member of the **Administrators** security group on Windows server.

After that you can try below items:

- Install the [TFS 2010 SP1 Cumulative Update 2 - KB2646719](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29078)
- Try upgrading to TFS [2012 **Update 4**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38185)  first, then try it
  again.

Related articles:

- [VS/TFS 2012.2 (Update 2) released today](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/04/04/vstfs-2012-2-update-2-released-today/)
- [TFS 2012 with Update 2 - Done](https://damianbrady.com.au/2013/05/04/tfs-2012-with-update-done-2/)

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the OP's feedback, the root cause was a project that has been deleted without source control folder. After executing `TFSProjectDelete.exe` и deleting from tables with [`project_id`] field all the rows containing information about this project, out migration has gone right way.

Comment: I have TFS **2010** SP1, not 2012 U1. And I try to upgrade to some later version like 2012 at least. I already tried 2012 U4, 2013 and 2015U1. None of them can complete because of this error.

Comment: @АлександрФеоктистов Sorry for the mistake, I have updated the answer, please have a try for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, although your suggestion didn't work for our case. But you made me search harder. The cause of our case was a project that has beed deleted without source control folder. After executing TFSProjectDelete.exe и deleting from tables with [project_id] field all the rows containing information about this project, out migration has gone right way. Now we have TFS 2018 installation.